# JQuery ASP.Net Performance Question

Tags: asp.net, jquery

The ASP.Net app (not MVC) is slow, someone heard that Jquery can speed things up by offloading work to the client.
Due to security reasons Jquery/Client can't make Web Service calls so squirrely ways of having the code behind making Web Sevices calls and passing data back to the client are being done to Jquery popups, Jquery gidviews, Jquery (fill in blank of existing server side control).
We've got Jquery AJAX going on along with Microsoft AJAX Update panels, which I'm worried about.

Question is: Are we really going to get a performance boost (which my gut says No) or are we on our way to a slower, more painful app performance?

Comment: What a hell are you talking about? The very same site you are visiting right now is built on top of ASP.NET and it serves millions of requests. Does it look slow to you? The fact that one writes poor code shouldn't serve as argument to generalize about the framework he is using.

Comment: I'm not saying ASP.Net is slow

Comment: I'm saying our specific ASP.Net application is slow.

Comment: And you expect us to doing something about it? You haven't provided even the slightest detail about your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't mix and match frameworks. It can cause problems and will certainly degrade performance. Choose one and stick to it. UpdatePanels are easy but will never be as fast as jQuery and web services.

http://encosia.com/2007/07/11/why-aspnet-ajax-updatepanels-are-dangerous/

Comment: When you say "jQuery and webs services", do you mean jQuery directly making the web service calls?

Comment: @mike yes. thats exactly what i meant.

Comment: and, if the code behind is making the web service calls and passing the data to jQuery it seems it would negate any jQuery speed enhancements, correct?

Comment: @mike: Am I correct in saying that what you're doing is, when an UpdatePanel posts back, you're calling a separate webservice in the code-behind, and then modifying the contents of the UpdatePanel accordingly? The difference between that and instead calling said webservice and updating the DOM accordingly, both via JavaScript/jQuery, is that there's one less server to wait for (your application server), and there's less data being sent down the wire, as updating an UpdatePanel will send EVERYTHING, whereas updating with JS will only request the bare data. See the Encosia post for more details.

Comment: jeff and adamjford, much better answers and attitude than Mr Dimitrov above

Answer (score 0):

I've never used the MS Ajax library but I have worked extensively with ASP.NET (webforms and MVC) and jQuery.

If this is an internal\intranet application or you don't need to worry about SEO, then using Ajax to pull content in will be fine.  It will help your pages load and render in the browser quicker but your data still wont be available.  You are really just breaking the hard work into several smaller components but the same amount of work is going to be done either way.

If you just care about getting a page rendered in the browser so that it doesn't feel (to the user) that its taking forever to load, then this is a great idea.  If that isn't the ideal outcome, you might want to focus your efforts on figuring out why its taking so long to load data.